# Display Notification when receiving C2DM message causes crash

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I want to display a message contained in my C2DM message's payload, but I can't seem to get this to work without crashing.

```
    package com.themenetwork.app;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("c2dm", "Message Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
            Log.w("c2dm", "Received message");
            final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
            Log.d("c2dm", "dmControl: payload = " + payload);

            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Hello", 0);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, RootActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title", "Text", contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        }
    }
}
```

The exception is...

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))
>     ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread$ReceiverData) line:
>   1881      ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread,
>   ActivityThread$ReceiverData) line: 124
>     ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1018
>     ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
>     Looper.loop() line: 130     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3806
>     Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native method]      Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 507      ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839
>     ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]

I'm really new to Java, let alone Android, so I'm completely stumped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: are you able to getting message in payload. some time it data in payload will came null.also can u upload all demo project which you have developed so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `myNotificationManager` null when you try to invoke `notify` on it? You need to initialize it to point to a valid instance of a `NotificationManager`, maybe like this:

```
myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```